# Must be STR, not DICT in Python

Tags: python

Here is the code I wrote now, but it won’t run due to a syntax error. The console says that *I must use str, not dict* at line 10. Can someone help me fix this?

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, ID, classno):
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.classno = classno
        
    def print_stu (self):
         print ("Student Name: " + {} + "\nStudent ID: " + {} + "\nCourse No: " + {}. foramt (self.name, self.ID, self.classno))
        
Jade = Student("Jad", str(37), str(82349))
Jade.print_stu()
```

Comment: Can you please quote (copy'n'paste) what output you get? Further, search for the error message to get an idea what it means. Also, if line 11 is never executed, that one is not part of a [mcve], along with the `print_stu()` definitions which is the clearly never used. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You're getting the formatting string wrong. `{}` outside a format string means an empty dict. You want `print ("Student Name: {}\nStudent ID: {}...".format (self.name, self.ID)`. But better to use f-strings.

Comment: In addition to what smci said: please also fix the typo (`foramt` instead of `format`).

Comment: Also it's not very Pythonic to have a method that actually calls `print`. Instead, your class should just have a `__str__()` method that `return`s the formatted string. Then you can `print(Jade)`, and that will implicitly call `Jade.__str__()`. And `print(Jade)` is much clearer interface than `Jade.print_stu()`

Answer (score 2):

Your `print_stu()` function is wrong. Since you had mentioned `{}` outside the string, when you format the string, it becomes `"....."+{}` where `{}` is an empty dictionary.

Also, there is a typo in `.format`. You wrote `.foramt`

```
def print_stu (self):
    print ("Student Name: {}\nStudent ID: {}\nCourse No: {}".format(self.name, self.ID, self.classno))
```